# JS - appendChild() and properly inherit css -> margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

have any of you noticed a lack of couple of pixels in margin when implementing appendChild method to insert elements?

For istance:

```
   <script>
    function tryit(){
        var d = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0],
        e   = document.getElementsByClassName("try");

        d.appendChild(e[0].cloneNode(true));
        d.removeChild(e[0]);
    }
    </script>
    <style>
    body{
        background-color:red;
    }
    div{
        padding:40px;
    }
    .try{
        margin:20px;
        padding:10px;
        background-color:white;
        border:5px solid black;
        color:blue;
    }
    </style>
    <button onclick="tryit()">try</button>
    <div>
    <span class="try">hello</span>
    <span class="try">hello</span>
    <span class="try">hello</span>
    <span class="try">hello</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Inspect it in the dev tools and see what css is responsible for this.

Comment: The line breaks between the `<span>`s count as white-space. You have spaces between your elements. When you append a child element, you’re not appending this white-space.